# What do "as both" and "both as" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, conjunction-reduction

Sometimes it's used as *"as both"* and sometimes as *"both as*", examples:

**His performance *both as* a captain and as a player was terrible.**

or

**I start with my own story, *as both* a means of explaining where I come from and, I hope, a way to show why I believe everyone is capable of change.**

Do they have different meanings in the examples and with what words could they be replaced keeping the same sense of those sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most certain rule is to use parallel forms after the words "both" and "and" in such a construction. By that rule, either say,

- **both as captain and as (a) player**

or

- **as both captain and (a) player.**

Certainly there are times when the "rule" is broken. If it is clear that a particular word ("as" in this case) has been left to be "understood", most people will find it natural, but some still may think it is an error. In a context (probably formal) where you really are worried about that possibility, it would be best to go for strict parallelism with the "both a" and "as" constructs.